Sample from Gaussian Measures on $\mathbb{R}^p$
Let us call a one-dimensional random variable to follow the normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ when $\sigma = 0$ if its distribution is the unit mass concentrated on $\mu$. When $\sigma > 0$, we use the usual definition. For an $\mathbb{R}^p$ valued random variable $X$, we call it normal if $a^TX$ is one-dimensional normal for every $a \in \mathbb{R}^p$. (That is, $X$ has Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}^p$.)
Let $X$ be an $\mathbb{R}^p$ valued normal random variable with known expectation $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and known $p \times p$ covariance matrix $\Sigma$. If $\Sigma > 0$, then $X$ is just the usual $N_p(\mu, \Sigma)$ and there are lots of methods to generate it. So let us suppose that $\Sigma$ is not invertible. How do we sample from $X$?
This question is motivated by my project, where I have to sample from the conditional distribution of an $\mathbb{R}^p$ valued random variable $X$ with $N_p(\mu, \Sigma)$ distribution with $\Sigma > 0$ knowning that $AX = b$, where $A$ is a known $q \times p$ matrix and $b \in \mathbb{R}^q$ is a known vector. Computing this conditional distribution $P_{X \mid AX = b}$ is an easy task and the solution can be found for example at Normal distribution conditional on a sub-affine space.
It turns out that $P_{X \mid AX = b}$ is a Gaussian measure with the problem stated above and I do not know how to generate it. To see that it could be singular, just take $p = q = A = 1$.

Diagonalize the covariance matrix. Your multivariate gaussian is now composed of $p$ univariate Gaussians with some known means and variances.

I don't really get the problem. Let $Y$ be an $n\times d$ matrix of iid univariate normal random variables. Since $\Sigma = V\Lambda V^{-1}$ for some orthogonal matrix $V$ and a diagonal matrix $\Lambda$. It follows that $\Sigma^{\frac 12} = V\Lambda^{\frac 12}V^{-1}$. Then $X = Y\Sigma^{\frac12}$ is a sample from $\mathcal N(0,\Sigma)$.
